# Displaying wallpaper when desktop is locked in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login, desktop, lock-screen

is it possible to lock the desktop in Windows 7 and have it continue to display your desktop wallpaper rather than the default Win7 locked-workstation screen?

Comment: Which wallpaper is "yours"? The last user who was interactively logged in? You want two users being able to fight for which of their wallpapers appears on the welcome screen? What if another user doesn't want to see your wallpaper?

Comment: Bump -how do I do this using Windows natively (meaning, without add-in products)? I just want windows 7 to show my current background wallpaper on the lock screen. Is that even possible?

I am not referring to the reg change where I can override the background.bmp - I want to see the current desktop background.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can. All you need is a small utility called [Logon Changer](http://tweaks.com/software/tweakslogon/) from tweaks.com. It would allow you to change the logon/lock screen to whatever image you'd like. And you can even test it beforehand, to see where the mandatory buttons fit in.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one which worked for me
[link](http://www.howtogeek.com/112110/how-to-set-a-custom-logon-screen-background-on-windows-7/)