# Set Windows 7 Lock Screen Background

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, lock-screen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying wallpaper when desktop is locked in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/114143/displaying-wallpaper-when-desktop-is-locked-in-windows-7)

I've googled this a bit, but have yet to find anything.

I have 2 monitors. when I lock my screen via win+L, it turns 1 of them off/black, and the other one is the win 7 login screen.

I would like to keep my current wallpaper as the background and on the two monitors if possible when the pc is locked.

Comment: i've posted an answer on this duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/114143/displaying-wallpaper-when-desktop-is-locked-in-windows-7/153021#153021

Answer (score 2):

I use a program called Tweek Login http://download.cnet.com/Tweaks-com-Logon-Changer/3000-2094_4-10911825.html

Comment: Works great for 1 monitor, is there a setting for the second monitor?

Comment: I thought it did...